# Retrieve oauth access token using azure implicit flow

Tags: node.js, azure, active-directory

I am using the azure node based api to set up an implicit flow of oauth v2. Upon typing in the url within the browser, although the page doesn't return anything - the browser url is updated to contain access_token and other parameters, following the redirect. I am looking to extract these by using a curl command instead and execute it in nodejs on the server side. I have been trying to send in the below curl request:

```
curl -i -g -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"client_id":"[client_id]","response_type":"id_token+token","scope":"open_id api://[client_id]/access_as_user","response_mode":"fragment","state":"12345","nonce":"678910","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3000/account/"}" 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
```

the error i am getting is :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-ms-request-id: b64ffac8-500a-48c9-ab61-7e64d74f0600
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=005; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 09:02:16 GMT
Content-Length: 381

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90004: Malformed JSON\r\nTrace ID: b64ffac8-500a-48c9-ab61-7e64d74f0600\r\nCorrelation ID: 64d444f1-1dd6-4ba6-b75f-876778515239\r\nTimestamp: 2018-01-10 09:02:19Z","error_codes":[90004],"timestamp":"2018-01-10 09:02:19Z","trace_id":"b64ffac8-500a-48c9-ab61-7e64d74f0600","correlation_id":"64d444f1-1dd6-4ba6-b75f-876778515239"}
```

At this point, I created a node app, and using adal-js to retrieve the access token on the end point.

```
var express = require('express');

var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var app = express();
var authorityUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' + sampleParameters.tenant + '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&response_type=<response_type>&scope=api://<client_id>/access_as_user&response_mode=<response_mode>&state=<state>&nonce=<nonce>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/account';

app.get('/account', function(req, res) {
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
  authenticationContext.acquireToken(authorityUrl, function(err, response) {
    var message = '';
    if (err) {
      message = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
    }
    message += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);

    if (err) {
      res.send(message);
      return;
    }
});
app.listen(3000);
```

The error, I see on the browser, when i log in: (note that all valid parameters have been entered above)

```
Error: acquireToken requires a function callback parameter.
```

Could anyone help with resolving the issue - trying to extract the access token from the output?

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) is used for JavaScript Single Page Application (SPA), while [adal-node](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) is used for Azure AD v1.0 endpoint, not for v2.0 endpoint. See [Azure AD v2.0 authentication libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries).

For your scenario (Node.js Web API), I would recommend you use [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) to protect your Web APIs. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-api) is a step by step instruction for securing a web API by using Node.js.